# Algorithm for generating sequence denoting the sequence of removal of numbers

Tags: algorithm, stack, queue

Given a finite sequence of numbers, in each round, any number whose left neighbour is smaller than itself will be removed. This removal action will continue until nothing can be removed. Each number removed will be labelled with the round it was removed, or 0 if it is never removed.

For example, consider the sequence

0 9 8 7 9 8 7 5

After first round, it becomes,

0 8 7 8 7 5

and after consecutive 4 rounds,

0 7 7 5

0 7 5

0 5

0

Thus the corresponding labels for the numbers are

0 1 2 3 1 2 4 5

How may I generate the sequence of labels in O(N) time by using a stack or queue, when N is the length of the sequence offered? Or may I know the maximum rounds of removing in O(N) time?

Comment: I cannot answer your question but I have some observations that might be helpful. Observation 1. The leftmost element will never be removed because it does not have a left neighbor. Observation 2. If the whole sequence is non-strict decreasing, the sequence will not be removed. Observation 3. If we partition the sequence into consecutive non-strict decreasing subsequences (this is different from the usual definition of a subsequence), then it is precisely the first element of those subsequences that will be removed, except for the leftmost element in the whole sequence.

Comment: If this question comes from an online judge could you edit your question to give the link to the original problem please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it can be done using a single stack, I will describe the solution, and briefly explain why it works later.

Assume the array is `A = [0, 9, 8, 7, 9, 8, 7, 5]`, `Ans = [] be the array of corresponding answer`. We also maintain an initially empty stack `S`. The stack will store pairs `{A[i], Ans[i]}` and we will try to preserve the stack so that it is always **strictly increasing** on `A[i]` as follows:

1. Push `{A[0], 0}` to `S`
2. Loop through array `A`. For an instance of iteration, let `A[i]` be current number (`Ans[i]` not known yet):

   2a. Initialize a variable `round_to_wait = 0`, keep popping the stack `S` until the top element is smaller than `A[i]`, set `rount_to_wait` to maximum `Ans[x]` meanwhile

   2b. If the `S` is empty, then set `Ans[i] = 0`, else set `Ans[i] = round_to_wait + 1`

   2c. Push `{A[i], Ans[i]}` to `S`

---

Let's do an demo based on your example:

1. `A = [0, 9, 8, 7, 9, 8, 7, 5], Ans = [0, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1], S = [{0,0}]`
2. `A[1] = 9 and S.top()` already smaller than 9, no element is popped. `Ans[1] = round_to_wait + 1 = 0 + 1 = 1`, push `{9, 1}` into `S`

   `A = [0, 9, 8, 7, 9, 8, 7, 5], Ans = [0, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1], S = [{0,0}, {9,1}]`
3. `A[2] = 8` and we popped element until `{0,0}` is left. `rount_to_wait = 1` as it is the maximum in whole popping process. `Ans[2] = round_to_wait + 1 = 1 + 1 = 2`, push `{8, 2}` into `S`

   `A = [0, 9, 8, 7, 9, 8, 7, 5], Ans = [0, 1, 2, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1], S = [{0,0}, {8,2}]`
4. Similarly, `S = [{0,0}, {7,3}]`
5. Similarly, `S = [{0,0}, {7,3}, {9,1}]`
6. Similarly, `S = [{0,0}, {7,3}, {8,2}]`
7. Similarly, `S = [{0,0}, {7,4}]`
8. Similarly, `S = [{0,0}, {5,5}]`

And that's it, you have the answer in one loop. As each element at most be pushed and popped one time, the complexity is still `O(N)`

---

Why it works is because,  Let `A[i]` be the first element which does not form strictly increasing sequence with `S`, what does that mean?

That means that, at some point, the top element in `S` `S_top` will "block" us from removing `A[i]`. We have chances (not sufficient condition though) to remove `A[i]` only if `S_top` is removed, which means it is at least as soon as `Ans[S_top] + 1`, and we take the maximum among all such elements.

The special case is that, there is no element smaller than `A[i]` at all, which means `S` will eventually be empty, in such case `Ans[i] = 0`

---

*(PS: I thought I have some memory on this problem on some online judge a few years ago, if that's the source, may you post it out so that I can go and submit to verify the solution?)*

Comment: For {0,9,11,7,6,5,10,6,9}.  {0,0}  {(0,0),(9,1)}  {(0,0),(9,1),(11,1)}  But it should be {(0,0),(9,1),(11,2)}.

Comment: Why? If I did not misunderstand the problem,  numbers which meet the requirement will be removed at the same round.

Comment: Yeah Probably. My Bad.